# Fetch network device info using SNMP

Tags: c#, asp.net, networking, snmp, mib

I am developing a network Management system where devices are discovered and fetch there information using SNMP, but am confused on MIB's and OID's and how to fetch network device info using these ?

Should I configure manually the MIB's and OID's or there is any way of doing this automatically ?

Any kind of help will be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want to recursively walk the MIB.

Comment: Read the wiki article is will answer a lot of your questions : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol

Comment: I am confused on how to identify SNMP version and how to configure OID for different network Devices.